# create variables from each element's id attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

need to create a variable from each element's `id` attribute - using jquery
as a final result - `btngo.on('click'...` - should work
any help

```js
$('body *').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('id')){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(id); // ok
        $(window)[id] = $(this); // here is the problem
    }
});

btngo.on('click', function(){
    console.log('btngo clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='btngo'>GO</button>
```

Comment: `btngo` would already be a global variable with that element, for backwards compatibility reasons, so you *could* just do `$(btngo)` and call it a day. But that's so 90s XD

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - what about `$('#btngo')` ? it also works. and is there a way to avoid `$(btngo)` - and use just `btngo` - and so for all elements on page

Comment: Yes you *can* do that, but you really shouldn't. Global variables are unreliable - any piece of code you write could overwrite them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply

```js
document.body.querySelectorAll('[id]').forEach(el=>console.log(el.id))
btngo.onclick = () => console.log('btngo clicked' )

/* same as:

window.btngo.onclick = () => console.log('btngo clicked' )

// or 

window['btngo'].onclick = () => console.log('btngo clicked' )

--------*/
```

```html
<button id='btngo'>GO</button>
```

within an array :

```js
const Elements = [...document.body.querySelectorAll('[id]')]
    .reduce((list, el) => 
      {
      list[el.id] = document.getElementById(el.id)
      return list
      }, {})
 
Elements['btngo'].onclick = () => console.log('btngo clicked' )
```

```html
<button id="btngo">Click me</button>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. So do I need to use jquery at all? what is the main benefit of using it, pls?

Comment: @deepSea no,my code is only JS, you don't need to use jQuery, it's already a big benefit in itself (javascript has evolved a lot since jQuery was born, many of the jQuery features are largely integrated in the JS; there is also the means that browsers now all respect the same HTML5, CSS, JS syntax; (which was not the case before)

Comment: I see, thanks. on forums many people say - jquery is a must for shortening the code, but as I can see - it's not the truth

Comment: @deepSea it was that true, until 2010 ~ ...? was that true, until 2010 ~ ...? but now there is React, vue.js and a lot of other stuff